# How to evaluate the integral $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty(\sigma^2)^{n/2+1}e^{-a/\sigma^2}d\sigma^2$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics

I want to evaluate this integral:

$\qquad \displaystyle\int_0^\infty(\sigma^2)^{n/2+1}e^{-a/\sigma^2}d\sigma^2$

Mathematica produces the following error message:

> Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in {σ^2, 0, ∞}.

I notice it does not recognize $d\sigma^2$ but only $d\sigma$.

However $\sigma^2$ is just a variable so I changed it to $\sigma$ and got

$\qquad a^{-n/2}\Gamma(n/2)$

which is not the answer I expected. It should be

$\qquad (a/2)^{-n/2}\Gamma(n/2)$.

How can I fix this?

---

Mathematica input

```
Integrate[(σ^2)^(-1 - n/2)/E^(a/σ^2), {σ^2, 0, Infinity}]
```

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: @MichaelE2 I edited the question

Comment: Thanks. You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: By the way, I think your expected answer is incorrect.  Here's a numeric comparison you can play with: `Block[{a = 3, n = 4.1},
 {NIntegrate[(\[Sigma])^(-1 - n/2)/E^(a/\[Sigma]), {\[Sigma], 0, 
    Infinity}],
  ConditionalExpression[a^(-n/2) Gamma[n/2], 
   Re[n] > 0 && ((Re[a] == 0 && Re[n] < 2) || Re[a] > 0)]}
 ]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 why  did you not use `\[Sigma]^2`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I don't know what you mean with your numeric example, why my expected answer is incorrect?

Comment: I didn't use `Sigma^2` because you cannot use that expression as a variable and you said "$\sigma^2$ is just a variable."  To me that says I can change $\sigma^2$ to any other symbol, like `x`, or as you said you did, `\[Sigma]`. If you do that, the iintegral does not give the answer you expected. If $\sigma$ in the original integral is the variable, so that $d\sigma^2$ is $d(\sigma^2) = 2\sigma\,d\sigma$, then you still get the same answer, of course, namely $a^{-n/2}\Gamma(n/2)$, not your expected answer $(a/2)^{-n/2}\Gamma(n/2)$. `NIntegrate` verifies this in my numeric example.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I checked with this `Integrate[2/(E^(a/\[Sigma])*\[Sigma]^(n/2 + 1)), {\[Sigma], 0, Infinity}]` and produces `ConditionalExpression[2 a^(-n/2) Gamma[n/2], 
 Re[n] > 0 && ((Re[a] == 0 && Re[n] < 2) || Re[a] > 0)]` it's not what you said: $a^{-n/2}\Gamma(n/2)$ because of the missing $2$

Comment: You put an extra factor of `2` in the integrand!

Comment: @MichaelE2 Why did you said this _If  in the original integral is the variable, so that $^2$ is $(^2)=2,$ then you still get the same answer, of course, namely $^{−/2}Γ(/2)$ then?

Comment: Is the hypothesis (about $\sigma$) true or is it false? If false, it doesn't matter.  If true, then that's why I said it. -- Please show why your expected value is correct.  Right now, either it's wrong or I don't know what you mean.  A proof of the expected answer might show me what integral you think you're doing.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I thought it was true because I saw the result on a 'paper', but is indeed false. I know realize about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the integral formula is ok we only have to rename (not to substitute!) the variable `\[Sigma]^2` by `\[Sigma]2` and get

```
Integrate[(\[Sigma]2)^(-1 - n/2)/E^(a/\[Sigma]2), {\[Sigma]2, 0,Infinity}, Assumptions -> {Re[a] > 0, Re[n] > 0}]
(*a^(-n/2) Gamma[n/2]*)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can I ask what do you mean with _If the integral formula is ok.._ ?

Comment: That means: The symbol `\[Sigma]^2` is the name of the integration variable.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
Integrate[x^{n/2 + 1}*Exp[-a/x], {x, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {n \[Element] Integers, a > 0}]
```

> {ConditionalExpression[a^(2 + n/2) Gamma[-2 - n/2], n < -4]}

[image]

Comment: Why your answer does not coincide with the one I mentioned above?

Comment: @user62732 I have no idea. Possibly the same, just an alternative form? My MMA is ver 11.3.